# Unable to open the link after file upload in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am performing a task in Java Struts2 Framework. Task is uploading a file and view the file when click on a specific link.

Problem is I am able to upload the file in desired folder. But when click on link It is giving 404 error, although file is uploaded in correct location as in link.

If I refresh project, then I am able to see the file on same link.

Without refreshing project, Can we see the file in browser in STRUTS2 framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a server in eclipse then it may be resolved when you deploy it on the Apache Tomcat Server because when you run on internally all data stored in the cache memory which is temporary while the server is running once you stop the server you will lose your data.

Answer (score 0):

You just create the method to open the uploaded file, and use () tag to instead of anchor tag for Link and call the action mapped with file opening method. In method you just write the code to open the file on client computer.